# Disable restart shortcut in VMWare?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vmware-workstation

I have set Ctrl-Alt-Win to be my hotkey for getting out of a VM and into the host. This works fine. Unfortunately, sometimes when I switch between the VM and the host and want to refresh a browser, I sometimes press Ctrl-R before having focus *within* the VM, thus sending Ctrl-R to the VMWare program, not its guest OS. That causes it to reboot the current VM ...

This happens quite often, so I would like to disable those `Ctrl-` combinations, but I cannot figure out how. VMWare lets me change [Hot-Key combinations](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/16.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-7D561C91-A3B4-42FD-8D71-85659D86400F.html), but I cannot see anything targetting the actual Ctrl- combinations.

How can I disable the reboot shortcut key combo?
[image: example image]

Comment: Wow, that's one dumb set of defaults. It's 10 times harder to accidentally take a screenshot than it is to shut the VM down.

Comment: @John I think you might be confused about the issue. Hotkeys fumbling is not the issue. I just have issues with the shortcuts for restarting the machine, as they are too easy to hit by mistake.

Comment: "VMware defaults inside a VM" is not the issue. My issue happens when you are on the host, switch back to VMWare and immediately hit Ctrl-R to refresh the browser you see. And then realize you hit the shortcut before ensuring the guest os has focus. This is not an issue in fullscreen, of course, just when you have windowed VMWare. But it makes the normal workflow different, which is a bit unfortunate. I never want to reboot using a shortcut; this is one of the few times I would grab my mouse :)

Comment: John, if you are a fast coder, you never use the mouse and you have muscle memory on what to do. It is true it asks for confirmation, but that confirmation is pressed when you are in a string of actions. The confirmation is pressed before you realize it was there. I would like help in disabling the shortcuts, not emphasis on how you think this is not an issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133549/discussion-between-oligofren-and-john).

Comment: @Tetsujin The keyboard shortcut for taking a screenshot is intentionally a bit obtuse because that specific shortcut is intended to work *within the guest*, so avoiding collisions is more important.  Additionally, its keyboard shortcut is tied to the ungrab hotkeys (Ctrl+Alt+Win in the OP's case); a simpler ungrab hotkey would result in a simpler shortcut.  We did put quite a bit of thought into those "dumb" defaults.

Comment: I highly recommend setting the host and guest to use different mouse cursors to make it much more obvious when you're grabbed and when you're not.  I also recommend re-enabling hints to re-enable the confirmation prompt when rebooting.

Comment: I have obviously somehow disabled those hints (new term) at some point, but was able to find a guide on re-enabling them once I knew the terminology: https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/Problem-with-hint-box-when-using-VMWare-KVM/td-p/1420367. I will try that first thing Monday when back to work. Regarding mouse, that would not help all that much, this happens too fast. I switch between Windows and VMWare and hit "refresh" in the browser all the time, it's less than a couple of second of total action time. No time to observe where the mouse is.

Comment: Fair enough.  Another (albeit intrusive) option would be to make a habit of pressing Ctrl+G first to ensure that the subsequent Ctrl+R goes to the guest.  Or perhaps use `vmware-kvm` and use a hotkey to switch between the host and a fullscreen VM.  I agree that Ctrl+R is an unfortunate shortcut; we weren't particularly happy about that either, but existing inertia was hard to overcome.

Comment: This shortcut choice is utterly insane...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [a thread on the VMWare forums from 2007](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/VMware-Workstation-Pro/Disabling-Power-related-keyboard-shortcuts-in-VMWare-Workstation/td-p/1062154) that listed some solutions. They all involved modifying the executable, by using a resource editor that could remove the "accelerators".

> Inside the vmware.exe resources are two accelerator groups, 115 and 41909. Each contains the line that I suspect is the culprit:
>
> `VK_R, 40021, NOINVERT, CONTROL, VIRTKEY`
>
> the parts to look at are the modifier keys (`CONTROL`) and the virtual key code (`VK_R`). The rest of the fields are only meaningful to the developers.

This does seem quite promising, as it promises to solve my problem

> removing the `VK_R` key solved my inadvertent rebooting vm with `^r`.

**Background info**

> An accelerator table is a C++ Windows resource that contains a list of accelerator keys, known as shortcut keys, and the command identifiers that are associated with them. A program can have more than one accelerator table.

source: [Microsoft C++ Accelerator Editor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/accelerator-editor?view=msvc-170)

## Verified solution

I just verified the above solution to work. The first thing to do is find a resource editor. I found Resource Tuner by Heaventools which lists [just this feature](http://www.restuner.com/howto-edit-accelerator-item.htm). I then made a copy of the original `vmware.exe` and used Resource Tuner to open the `vmware.exe` and find the accelerator table:

[image: shortcuts]

You then get the possibility of deleting or editing an entry. I chose to edit them by adding `Alt` as a modifier key and verified that indeed pressing `Ctrl-Alt-R` did immediately reboot my machine. The changed Full window of how it looked after the change:
[image]